# Converting canonical regular expression from C# to ECMAScript C++ syntax

Tags: c#, c++, regex, ecmascript-6

I tried to use the following regular expression, which already works in C#, in C++ as well but it's not working in C++.

```
std::regex r = std::regex("([^%]*(%[.[0-9]*]?[a-z])*)*", std::regex::extended);
```

it manages to match several strings and reject others correctly, but gets stuck (really stuck - no error) on the string "%d smaller than available pbn % f %d", which it should reject (since there is a % that's not immediately preceded by a legal suffix).

Using std::regex r = std::regex("(([^%]*)(%(\.([0-9]*))?[a-z])*)*"); exhibits exactly the same behavior i described before. (i assume those two regexes are equivalent - just one is in canonical form like C# uses and the second is ECMAScript like the c++ default)

Just to give an example of what I want the regular expression to match is:

Got event %s (%d) in state %s (%d), moving to state %s (%d) ...

or

Some %.34x event

And the regular expression is supposed not to match the following:

Some % stuff

To explain in words what the regex should do - it should accept the only string that all the occurrences (if any) of % in them is immediately preceded by a letter or by a .46456x (aka . some numbers and a letter) and reject all others.

Comment: Just FYI: C++ regular expressions *default* to ECMAScript-type regexes. But there are [other possible variants](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/syntax_option_type) as well.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdudec is any of those option the canonical form C# uses by default?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude thanks - i have tried using the std::regex::extended option and it seems to recognize the regex in C# style - ([^%]*(%[.[0-9]*]?[a-z])*)*". It works for several strings correctly, but when trying to use it on the string ""%d smaller than available pbn % f %d" it gets inexplicably stuck - it doesn't throw an error, just gets stuck. will appreciate some help understanding this.